# Instant update/show what's written in the input box using onkeydown Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to simultaneously show what's written in the input box in div message, but the result is always 1 step before/backward.

```
function showWhatsWritten(){
  var tempText;
  tempText = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = tempText;
}

<input id="text" type="text" onkeydown="showWhatsWritten()"/>
<div id="message"></div>
```

The result is always like this:

```
input: 123456

output: 12345  (missing 6)

input: abcde

output: abcd (missing e)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that the input is updated already when key down event is fired. Try key pressed or key up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the right event, `onkeyup`. [Try the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HDy2k/):

```
<input id="text" type="text" onkeyup="showWhatsWritten()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now! but what's wrong with onkeydown? Surely when a key is pressed 'down' an event is triggered?

Comment: Definitely, your event is triggered immediately as soon as you press key down. The problem is that keydown is a keyboard event that fires *immediately* when your key is pressed and before the value of the actual input itself is updated to react to the key being pressed. That's why you were getting the `input` value and were seeing that it had not yet been updated.

Answer (score 0):

More a comment than answer.

You can greatly simplify your code:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML=this.value
">
```